# Does table expansion happen only on using table name? Or also on using column name?

Tags: powerbi, dax

```
SUMX(TBLNAME, 1)

SUMX(ALL(TBLNAME), 1)

SUMX(ALL(TBLNAME[COLNAME]), 1)
```

Does table expansion happen only in 1st and 2nd example? What about the 3rd example. Is there any general list of situations when table expansion occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table expansion happens for tables. When single columns are specified, there is no table expansion. Therfore for sample 3 there is no table expansion.

Assuming to have a model with a one to many relationship between table D and table F (on column ID) and a measure M

In a visual with D[cd] on the rows, the forumula

```
CALCULATE( [M], FILTER (ALL(F), F[cf] = val) )
```

uses expanded table therefore removing any existing filter over D

the formula

```
CALCULATE( [M], FILTER (ALL(F[cf]), F[cf] = val) )
```

instead only affects F[cf] column and doesn't affect filters over D table

Comment: Usually does expansion happen when SUMX is used? I imagine that it does because that is how it has access to the related coloumns?

Comment: Yes, when the first parameter of SUMX is a table,like for instance in SUMX( T, ... ) or SUMX( ALL( T ) ....) it is expanded.

Comment: Also, in following case- CALCULATE ( SUM(T[C]) , filter), table T does get expanded. Otherwise how would CALCULATE perform the filter. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, it can be seen as the filter that operates over the expanded table. But I think it's important to add that the expanded table is an abstract concept: it is not actually materialized in memory.